# seekbar thumb position change when user press device volume keys

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget

Im using seek bar to control volume of the device. Im able to change the volume of the device using thumb of the seek bar just by dragging it on touch pad.

But when user presses volume(side) keys i need to set seek bar thumb position accordingly.

Hw i can do this please let me know

Thanks

Comment: Can you please share the code?

Comment: @Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
   int index = seekbar.getProgress();
   seekbar.setProgress(index + 1);
   return true;
  } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
   int index = seekbar.getProgress();
   seekbar.setProgress(index - 1);
   return true;
  }
  return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got solution, by overriding onkeydown event.

```
     @Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) 
    { 
           int index = seekbar.getProgress(); 
           seekbar.setProgress(index + 1); 
           return true; 
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)
     {
           int index = seekbar.getProgress(); 
           seekbar.setProgress(index - 1); 
           return true; 
    }
     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
    }
```

Edited for further reference