# Android: How I call in runOnUiThread method to onKeyDown?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have this code of onKeyDown method:

```
 @Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) 
    { 
           int index = seekbar.getProgress(); 
           seekbar.setProgress(index + 1); 
           return true; 
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)
     {
           int index = seekbar.getProgress(); 
           seekbar.setProgress(index - 1); 
           return true; 
    }
     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
    }
```

The problem is that I would like do this in an `AsyncTask`, on `postExecute` and I think inside runOnUiThread, but I don't sure.

any ideas or suggestions about do this?

thanks!

EDIT:

I have a seekBar in dialog which is created and showed in postExecute in a AsynTask, and I need update the seekbar thumb position like this: [seekbar thumb position change when user press device volume keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215791/seekbar-thumb-position-change-when-user-press-device-volume-keys)

Comment: Why you want to do this?

Comment: onKeyDown() is method for Activity not for AsyncTask and you can't called directly this method.

Comment: because I have a seekBar in dialog which is created and showed in postExecute in a AsynTask, and I need update the seekbar thumb position like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215791/seekbar-thumb-position-change-when-user-press-device-volume-keys

Comment: Make a Seekbar reference globally, then you can do it in normal way no need to put this method onPostExecute().

Answer (score 0):

`postExecute` does not need `runOnUiThread` you can update UI elements in `postExecute`

for more information read [this.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 0):

take a boolean variable

```
boolean myboolean=false;
```

then make this variable "true" in your `postExecute()`

and edit your `onKeyDown()` method as

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(myboolean)
    {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) 
        { 
            int index = seekbar.getProgress(); 
            seekbar.setProgress(index + 1); 
            return true; 
        } 
        else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)
        {
            int index = seekbar.getProgress(); 
            seekbar.setProgress(index - 1); 
            return true; 
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 class ABC {

        Context mContext;

        ABC(Context c)
        {
        mContext=c; 
        }


        public void launchIntent() {
           CurrentClass.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {


                call your method stub here
                } 
            }
           });
        }
     }
```